# VBA Property not equalled

Tags: vba, excel, properties

Just a quick question on VBA. I know it's basic but it will clean the spiders nest in my brain

A property is almost always being set equal to something, or perhaps the value of a property is being assigned to something else. Is there any occasion where you do not see this happening? I am scouring my VBA books but i cannot actually find any situation like this.

Property being set equal:

```
ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = Range(“A1”).Interior.ColorIndex

Cells(FinalRow + 1, 1).Value = “Total”
```

**thanks for watching my question**

Comment: Properties can either be read ("get") or written ("set"). In your example the RHS of the statement `ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = Range(“A1”).Interior.ColorIndex` is "getting" the `ColorIndex` property of the `Range` class. IOW, it's not setting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties of VBA are always set either one of two ways (ignoring "Setting" Objects for now although essentially they are the same as the first type below).

You can set a constant, in the form of a string or value. This is a fixed constant that will always be static no matter how you run the code (ie `Activecell.Value = "Total"`

You can assign a variable, which will change depending on how you run the code or the contents of a certain cell/value (ie. `Activecell.Value=Range ("A1").Value`, as A1's value could be changed by anything.

For the sake of completeness, Setting an Object using `Dim x As Object: Set x =CreateObject ("...") ... Set x = Nothing` are all fixed and therefore constant. Obviously this could then be used to reference a filepath generated by a variable, but that initial set is fixed (this is why I did not use the get and set terminology as mentioned earlier).

If you think about it, almost every problem is only ever made up of constants and variables.

Comment: Sir I am sorry work has spiraled out of control here i will absolutely have time tomorrow to see this thorougly